# jqGrid navigation button fired post method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

jqGrid

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllAuthors", "Admin")',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'get',
        colNames: ['Yazar Adı', 'Öz Geçmiş'],
        colModel: [
                  { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: false },
                  { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: false }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "sno",
            root: "rows", //array containing actual data
            page: "page", //current page
            total: "total", //total pages for the query
            records: "records", //total number of records
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
        sortname: 'Name',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        width: 710,
        height: 300
    })
    .navGrid('#gridpager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false })
    .navButtonAdd('#gridpager', {
        caption: "Düzenle",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var grid = $("#grid");
            var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            //alert(rowid + " - " + grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'CustomerName') + " - Link: " + $("#customers_grid_table a.customer_details").attr("href"));
            window.location = '@Url.Action("EditAuthor", "Admin")?authorId=' + rowid;
            //LoadAction('@Url.Action("EditAuthor", "Admin")?authorId=' + rowid);
        }
    });  //end jqgrid
});
```

I have two method in my controller

Get method

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditAuthor(int authorId)
```

Post method

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAuthor(AuthorViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

I selected a row and clicked edit button, I expect to fire get method, but post method is fired. What can I do to fire get method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set new value of `window.location` the HTTP GET will be used. To produce HTTP POST you can either use `$.ajax` or submit some form. You can for example dynamically build invisible `<form>` and submit it. For example

```js
onClickButton: function () {
    var rowid = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
        myForm = document.createElement("form"),
        param1 = document.createElement("input");

    myForm.action = '@Url.Action("EditAuthor", "Admin")';
    myForm.method = "POST";
    myForm.style.display="none";

    param1.name = "authorId";
    param1.type = "text";
    param1.value = rowid;
    myForm.appendChild(param1);

    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    myForm.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(myForm);
}
```

I recommend you additionally to include additional validation whether some row is selected (whether `rowid` is not null).

Moreover I recommend you

- to use **always** `gridview: true` option in the grid which will just improve the performance of the grid.
- replace the option `pager: jQuery('#gridpager')` to `pager: '#gridpager'`.
- replace the current value of `jsonReader` option to `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "sno"}`. The options which you specify will be *combined* with default value (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data)). Additionally your current value of `jsonReader` option contains syntax error because you specify the same property `repeatitems: false` twice.

Comment: I dont want to post method. I want get method. I changed my codes to your suggestions. But still post method.

Comment: I m so sory, Its not about jqGrid. Its about my model types. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: Sorry, for misunderstanding. You are welcome!